# SwiftUI app crash with "attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update" error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My app started crashing randomly during launch with below error. Sometimes it starts and sometimes it crashes. How can I investigate this bug? Any help appreciated

```
2021-06-21 09:44:44.940545+0200 APP[18897:3547429] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001186ebfba __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000118595ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001186ebde3 +[NSException raise:format:] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010ffa88e7 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001245098a3 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 9269
    5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000124524ff7 -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 116
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001245251c9 -[UITableView _performBatchUpdates:withContext:completion:] + 253
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001245252af -[UITableView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 97
    8   SwiftUI                             0x000000011527a801 $s7SwiftUI25UpdateCoalescingTableView33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC19performBatchUpdates_10completionyyycSg_ySbcSgtF + 378
    9   SwiftUI                             0x000000011527a8da $s7SwiftUI25UpdateCoalescingTableView33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC19performBatchUpdates_10completionyyycSg_ySbcSgtFTo + 175
    10  SwiftUI                             0x000000011527d31d $s7SwiftUI19ListCoreCoordinator33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC17updateUITableView_2to11transactionySo0mN0C_xAA11TransactionVtF14performUpdatesL_yyAA0cD10DataSourceRzAA16SelectionManagerR_0V5ValueQy_AORtzr0_lF + 1594
    11  SwiftUI                             0x0000000115623652 $sIg_Ieg_TR + 12
    12  SwiftUI                             0x0000000115623668 $sIeg_IyB_TR + 14
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000124856bb9 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 84
    14  SwiftUI                             0x000000011527dc6f $s7SwiftUI19ListCoreCoordinator33_BFB370BA5F1BADDC9D83021565761A49LLC17updateUITableView_2to11transactionySo0mN0C_xAA11TransactionVtFyycfU_ + 467
    15  SwiftUI                             0x0000000115166eb7 $sIeg_ytIegr_TR + 12
    16  SwiftUI                             0x00000001152851cf $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA + 17
    17  SwiftUI                             0x000000011528899f $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA.42 + 9
    18  SwiftUI                             0x0000000115150ec4 $s7SwiftUI6UpdateO3endyyFZ + 433
    19  SwiftUI                             0x0000000114fa83fd $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE14flushObserversyyFZ + 148
    20  SwiftUI                             0x0000000114fa8367 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_yyXEfU_ + 9
    21  SwiftUI                             0x0000000114fa35fe $ss5Error_pIgzo_ytsAA_pIegrzo_TR95$sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_yyXEfU_Tf3npf_n + 14
    22  libswiftObjectiveC.dylib            0x0000000119a9603e $s10ObjectiveC15autoreleasepool8invokingxxyKXE_tKlF + 46
    23  SwiftUI                             0x0000000114fa8356 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_ + 35
    24  SwiftUI                             0x0000000114fa8459 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_To + 43
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000118658d31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000118653542 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 541
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000118653af5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1129
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001186531a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011c844d85 GSEventRunModal + 139
    30  UIKitCore                           0x000000012430c4df -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    31  UIKitCore                           0x000000012431139c UIApplicationMain + 101
    32  1A-Client                           0x000000010485fb5b main + 75
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000119e1cbbd start + 1
    34  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 772.1 - Device: iPhone 12 (6C4D1499-EBAC-4ED6-9C38-7DB0EB0C63E9) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) - DeviceType: iPhone 12
```

Comment: Set up breakpoints and debug the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this crash by forcing section rewrite on every view refresh. It looks not optimal but the problems seems to be problem with SwiftUI view update cycle

```
Section {
    content()
}
.id(UUID())
```